# Python - Should GUI be in separate file? Confused

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I have 2 features in 2 different files - feature1.py and feature2.py

I also have third file - main.py which import both features and use them together.

So the whole program is ran from the main.py file

I started doing GUI for first time and I'm really confused where to put the code?
I don't know if i should do it in main.py but then i can't add like progress bar for feature1 for example..

OR

Should it be in separate file and import it in every other file?

I'm not sure if it matters but I'm creating the GUI using PySimpleGUI with the tkinter port.

Apologies if it's noobish question.

Comment: Generally anything that you can discern about your program should be in its own module (aka file in python). That way any other part of your program can more easily reuse that functionality. Also this makes it more easy to share specific pieces of functionality with others.

Comment: How are you importing the other files?  Are you doing `from feature1 import *`, for example?  You would need to worry about name collisions.  But if you `import feature1`. all the references should be in the feature1 namespace, and referenced with `feature1.` preceding each value/function/class name, so there's no collision.

Comment: You're asking for opinions, and opinionated questions are off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @BryanOakley This is not opinion.  Some techniques work and some don't.  The OP is looking for techniques that work, not techniques that are better.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand there are arguments to be made that support both styles of coding, I have created a mini-example that will hopefully clarify how to do it in separate files.

File 1: Strings

```
class String:
    def __init__(self):
        self.string1 = "Hello World"

    def addString(self, string1, string2):
        return f"{string1} {string2}"

    def findLetter(self, string1, letter):
        if letter in string1:
            return "Occurrence Found"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = String()
```

File 2: Math Operations

```
class Math():
    def __init__(self):
        self.number1 = 1
        self.number2 = 2
        self.number3 = 3
        self.number4 = 4
        self.number5 = 5

    def addition(self, addend1, addend2):
        sum1 = addend1 + addend2
        return sum1

    def subtraction(self, subtrahend, minuend):
        difference = minuend - subtrahend
        return difference

    def multiplication(self, factor1, factor2):
        product = factor1 * factor2
        return product

    def division(self, dividend, divisor):
        quotient = dividend / divisor
        return quotient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    math = Math()
```

File 3: Main

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg 
import PracticeFunction2
from PracticeFunction1 import String

def main():
    math = PracticeFunction2.Math()
    string = String()
    sg.theme('BlueMono')

    layout =    [
                [sg.Text("\tThis is a test", font=('Times New Roman', 18, 'bold'))],
                [sg.Text("1st Number:\t", font=('',14)), sg.Input(default_text="", size=(5, 1), key='_number1_', font=('', 14), justification='center')],
                [sg.Text("2nd Number:\t", font=('',14)), sg.Input(default_text="", size=(5, 1), key='_number2_', font=('', 14), justification='center')],
                [sg.T('')],
                [sg.Button("Add", size=(10,1), key="_add_"), sg.Button("Subtract", size=(10,1), key="_sub_"),sg.Button("Multiply", size=(10,1), key="_mult_"),sg.Button("Divide", size=(10,1), key="_div_")],
                [sg.T('')],
                [sg.T('Solution:\t', font=('', 14)), sg.T("\t\t", font=('', 14), key='_solution_')],
                [sg.T('')],
                [sg.Text("1st String:\t\t", font=('',14)), sg.Input(default_text="", size=(5, 1), key='_string1_', font=('', 14), justification='center')],
                [sg.Text("2nd String:\t", font=('',14)), sg.Input(default_text="", size=(5, 1), key='_string2_', font=('', 14), justification='center')],
                [sg.T('')],
                [sg.Button("Add Strings", size=(15,1), key="_addString_"), sg.Button("Find Letter", size=(15,1), key="_findLetter_")],
                [sg.T('')],
                [sg.T('Result:\t', font=('', 14)), sg.T("\t\t", font=('', 14), key='_result_')],
                ]

    window = sg.Window("Multiple Files Testing", layout, finalize=True)

    while True:
        event, values = window.Read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        if event == "_addString_":
            answer = string.addString(values['_string1_'], values['_string2_'])
            window['_result_'].Update(value=f"{answer}")

        if event == '_findLetter_':
            answer = string.findLetter(values['_string1_'], values['_string2_'])
            window['_result_'].Update(value=f"{answer}")

        if event == "_add_":
            number1 = int(values['_number1_'])
            number2 = int(values['_number2_'])
            answer = math.addition(number1, number2)
            window['_solution_'].Update(value=f"{answer}")

        if event == "_sub_":
            number1 = int(values['_number1_'])
            number2 = int(values['_number2_'])
            answer = math.subtraction(number1, number2)
            window['_solution_'].Update(value=f"{answer}")

        if event == "_mult_":
            number1 = int(values['_number1_'])
            number2 = int(values['_number2_'])
            answer = math.multiplication(number1, number2)
            window['_solution_'].Update(value=f"{answer}")

        if event == "_div_":
            number1 = int(values['_number1_'])
            number2 = int(values['_number2_'])
            answer = math.division(number1, number2)
            window['_solution_'].Update(value=f"{answer}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Explanation: Files 1 and 2 contain classes that can be called by the Main file whenever I want to use those methods. My GUI is built completely within the Main file and just pulls from the other files whenever it needs to. Now, if I begin to work on another project, I can still use my Strings class and my Math Class without worry about incorporating all the unnecessary aspects of the Main file. Files 1 and 2 can be reused for any future project and is safe, reliable, reusable code.

Comment: Yes, that was my plan initially. My structure is exactly the same as yours.
BUT
If i want to add progress bar in one of the functions how can i do that? It needs to be in the function file rather than the main one?

Comment: @GoodDumbPerson If you're okay with having the progress bar by itself and not attached to the Main file GUI then it's not a problem. You would need to import PSG in the function file and set it up the same.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. What do you mean "set it up the same"

Comment: @GoodDumbPerson For instance, if you were to use code similar to the example in the cookbook (https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#custom-progress-meter-progress-bar) then you would have that code in the function file. It would be set up the same as if it were in the main file, but it's not.